# combination of multiple properties as node label

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to show first_name + last_name as label of my node. It seems like it only supports `data(first_name)`

```
"style": {
    "label": "data(first_name) + data(last_name)",
```

edit 1:
my style file is a JSON. It should be just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like currently, we have to use function styles. Below is an example that uses `first_name` + `last_name` as a label.

```
style({
  'label': (x) => {
    let s = '';
    const name = x.data('first_name');
    if (name) {
      s += name;
    }
    const name2 = x.data('last_name');
    if (name2) {
      s += ' ' + name2;
    }
    return s;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function like following:

```
"style": {
    label: function(ele) {
      return `${ele.data(first_name)} + data(last_name)"`
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Anton but my style file is a JSON. So it is just a string and can't reach to variables and functions.

Comment: you can make js file with export